# How to pass more than one parameter on frame navigation in Metro Style Apps?

Tags: c#, windows-8

I am building a Metro Style App for Win8 which requires to pass two textblock values on frame navigation. For one parameter, it works but for two parameters its not working. Please help!
I have tried like the following:
       this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage),textblock1.Text + textblock2.Text);

I doesn't show any error but its not working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a new class with 2 properties and set the properties to the textblock values. Then you pass this object when you navigate.

Create the payload class:

```
public class Payload
{
 public string text1 { get;set;}
 public string text2 { get;set;}
}
```

Then populate the payload class:

```
Payload payload = new Payload();
payload.text1 = textblock1.Text;
payload.text2 = textblock2.Text;
```

Then when you call Navigate pass your instance of payload like this:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage),payload);
```

Comment: how to get values in secondpage?

Comment: @rams http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da/winappswithcsharp/thread/8cb42356-82bc-4d77-9bbc-ae186990cfd5

Comment: Override the OnNavigate event on SecondPage to load the values from e.Parameter and cast it as the Payload, make sure to check for null. Hope that helps anyone out there.

Answer (score 1):

I have taken a dictionary object like this.

```
Dictionary<string, string> newDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
newDictionary.Add("time", itemObj.repTime);
newDictionary.Add("message", itemObj.repMessage);
Frame.Navigate(typeof(ViewDetails),newDictionary);
```

On ViewDetails.xaml.cs page I had retrieved the data like this,

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
         Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
         myDictionary = e.Parameter as Dictionary<string, string>;
         timeTB.Text = myDictionary["time"].ToString();
         messageTB.Text = myDictionary["message"].ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Only works if both params as of same type, like in your example. But doesn't work for different value types (int, float, etc....)

Comment: Yes, you are right. But the OP wanted to pass two text parameters in the question. I answered accordingly :)

Answer (score 0):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/8cb42356-82bc-4d77-9bbc-ae186990cfd5/passing-parameters-during-navigation-in-windows-8?forum=winappswithcsharp
same here ;)
i think this is what you want

Comment: Have you checked the link given by 4imble on Allan Muller's answer ? Moreover, if you think this is the answer to the original question, please copy/paste the relevant explanation (and code) in case the link disappear someday, thanks.